# OOP in Tkinter - Create Frame with Listbox

Tags: python, tkinter

Hey I would like to create a frame which contains a Listbox and some buttons. What I would like to do is to somehow pass as an argument a name of this listbox. This is my current code in which I set the name of this listbox to `master.thisListbox` but I would like to pass it somehow as argument. Is it possible or should I separately crate a listbox in my App and the pass it as an argument to a frame? I'm going to create a lot of such listboxes in my App hence the name of listbox shouldn't be the same. I'm pretty new in OOP.

```
class myApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.dateFrame = DateFrame(self)
        self.dateFrame.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        print(self.day.get())
        self.myFrame = ListboxFrame(self, "Label!", [1,2,3])
        self.myFrame.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
        
        x = self.thisListbox.get(0, END)
        print(x)

class DateFrame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        
        # Day
        ttk.Label(self, text = "Day", width = 4).grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 3, pady = 3)
        master.day = IntVar(master, value = 31)
        self.dayCB = ttk.Combobox(self, values = [x for x in range(1, 32)], textvariable = master.day, width = 4)
        self.dayCB.grid(row = 1, column = 0, padx = 3, pady = 3)
        # Month
        ttk.Label(self, text = "Month", width = 6).grid(row = 0, column = 1, padx = 3, pady = 3)
        self.month = IntVar(master, value = 12)
        self.monthCB = ttk.Combobox(self, values = [x for x in range(1, 13)], textvariable = self.month, width = 4)
        self.monthCB.grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx = 3, pady = 3)
        # Year
        ttk.Label(self, text = "Year", width = 4).grid(row = 0, column = 2, padx = 3, pady = 3)
        self.year = IntVar(master, value = 2021)
        self.yearCB = ttk.Spinbox(self, from_ = 2020, to = 2100, textvariable = self.year, width = 6)
        self.yearCB.grid(row = 1, column = 2, padx = 3, pady = 3)

class ListboxFrame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, labelText, values, selectmode = "extended", height = 6, width = 30):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        # Listbox
        ttk.Label(self, text = labelText).grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 3)
        master.thisListbox = tk.Listbox(self, selectmode = selectmode, height = height, width = width)
        master.thisListbox.grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 3, padx = 2, pady = 2)
        # Entry
        self.entry = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entry.grid(row = 2, column = 0, padx = 2, pady = 2)
        # Buttons
        self.addButton = ttk.Button(self, text = "Add", width = 4, command = self.Add)
        self.addButton.grid(row = 2, column = 1, padx = 2, pady = 2)
        self.deleteButton = ttk.Button(self, text = "Delete", width = 6, command = self.Delete)
        self.deleteButton.grid(row = 2, column = 2, padx = 2, pady = 2)
        
        for v in values:
            master.thisListbox.insert(END, v)
        
    def Add(self):
        if self.entry.get() == "": return
        master.thisListbox.insert(END, self.entry.get())
        self.entry.delete(0, END)
        
    def Delete(self):
        for index in reversed(master.thisListbox.curselection()):
            master.thisListbox.delete(index)
        # listbox.config(height = listbox.size())
```

Comment: Since you're going to be creating a lot of listboxes, why not have a list of them?

Comment: This sounds like a very bad design. Why not just reference the listbox off of the custom frame? `self.myFrame.listobox`?